# Using FORCESEEK on SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I was using this option for a long time on specific query, all of the sudden SQL Server throws this error:

> Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

What could be the reason for this error to be generated at this moment if nothing was changed in the stored procedure? I know is not recommended to used I just want to know why is working in one server but not in another?

Comment: Are both servers running the same version of `sql-server`?

Comment: Yes SQL Server 2014

Comment: Anybody can help me on this please?

Comment: "nothing was changed in the stored procedure" but apparently something changed on the indexing but without actual code and example index sample we can but of little assistance here